# Replaced catalytic converter, O2 sensor went out, Replaced it and check engine light is still on

Tags: chevrolet, o2-sensor, impala

About a month ago I replaced my catalytic converter, a few weeks later the O2 sensor went out. I replaced that too and I'm still getting a check engine light code for the same sensor. What else should I do? The guy at autozone said to make sure that the O2 sensor is getting power and that it's plugged in and it looks like it's getting power and it's plugged in.

Update- last two oil changes they've also said that my oil levels are dangerously low.. even though I've been changing the oil on time. Not sure if that's relevant or not.

Comment: You had the codes read again and cleared?

Comment: Yes I have! Same code

Comment: What is the make/model/year/engine of the car? What exactly is the code you are getting?

Comment: Chevy 2008 Impala, I believe the code is PO135 (Can't remember the exact code)- it's the O2 sensor bank 1 sensor 2

Comment: *Might actually be PO136

Comment: Who did the work on the catalytic converter? Was the cat broken in correctly? It's probably the P0136, then as that aligns to B1S2. My suggestion is to trace the wiring back towards the ECU from the O2 sensor to ensure it's not grounded out or broken somewhere. The code suggests the sensor voltage is too low, which could very well be a break in the wire or some other issue going on with the wiring. Also, check the O2 plug itself and make sure all of the pins are where they are supposed to be. Check both sides of the plug to be sure (O2 and wiring harness sides).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Triple A did the work on the catalytic converter. How should a catalytic converter be broken in? It looks like all of the pins are plugged in, I'll have to wait until I can get a lift to check the wiring.

Comment: To break in a cat, basically, run it at idle for 5 minutes on first startup, then bring it up to 2500 for another 2 minutes, shut the vehicle off and let it cool completely. This gives the honeycomb a chance to expand as it's supposed to. If not done correctly, the cat can self destruct in a month or so.

Comment: What engine do you have? On the Impala there shouldn't be a p0136 code. p0135 is for the b1s1 heater. A low voltage code on b1s2 would be a p0137 and a heater code for b1s2 would be p0141.

Comment: What is the mileage of the car? If the car is burning oil, this might have fouled the catalytic converter or the O2 sensor. The good news is that this can be fixed (but you need to fix the oil burning problem first).

Comment: The ECU on my '97 Golf 3 logged a lambda probe fault but before replacing the probe, I checked the wiring and found it to be frayed.  The n-cost repair was to address the wiring issue and clear the fault codes.

Comment: I have a V6 engine. The mileage is about 83,000.  I've started to think that it is burning oil but I'm not sure how to fix that

Comment: there are two possible v6 engines and a v8 that go in that year impala it doesn't look like there's much difference between the two v6s though. I'd verify the code first. If it is a heater circuit code you might want to wire in an amp meter inline to check draw. should be .5-2a.

Comment: I was completely wrong about the code- P0036 heater control circuit bank 1 sensor 2.

Answer (score 1):

Check the O2 sensor connector for pin fit and corrosion. You will have (I assume) ignition voltage (it may be 5v) on one heater wire and a pulse width modulated ground on the other heater wire.

If you don't have power and the Emissions 1 fuse isn't blown, voltage drop test the wire to find the break. If the fuse was blown I'd expect more codes than just the p0036 code.

If you do have power, check the ground wire. You would want to do this with a digital storage oscilloscope to check the waveform for drop outs. I think you can do this with a digital volt ohm meter as well since it's PWM you would see half the voltage you see on the power wire. Or if you had a known good spec you could try to get a hertz reading on the PWM wire.

If the wiring checks out try replacing the O2 sensor again before replacing the pcm.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the maker of the cat it’s also possible to have a defective new aftermakrket cat if it’s not an oe supply